# Changing Xvfb frame buffer resolution while it's running

Tags: linux, x11, framebuffer, xvfb

I run [Xvfb](https://www.x.org/releases/X11R7.6/doc/man/man1/Xvfb.1.xhtml) with command:

```
Xvfb :1 -screen 0 100x100x16 -fbdir /tmp
```

And it's working fine. I can connect via VNC, and now under `/tmp` directory I have `Xvfb_screen0` binary file.

I thought it will act like `/dev/fb0` so I tried to change its settings with [fbset](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/man1/fbset.1.html) like:

```
sudo fbset -fb /tmp/Xvfb_screen0 -xres 500 -yres 500
```

But the command finishes with error:

> ioctl FBIOGET_VSCREENINFO: Inappropriate ioctl for device

Is there any way to change running Xvfb server resolution?

Comment: Answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6356169/resizing-an-xvfb-display/46295657#46295657

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not certain that Xvfb supports resizing. If your main interest is VNC, perhaps you should try [TigerVNC](http://tigervnc.org/). It's a modern VNC server that supports RandR and Xinerama. Screen resizing and multiple monitors work very well in TigerVNC.

Comment: I can't see how TigerVNC is supposed to allow me to resize Xvfb's framebuffer. If `xrandr` is not working, how will `XrandR` work?

Comment: @Jezor I never implied that TigerVNC will support changing Xvfb. I was suggesting using TigerVNC instead of Xvfb+VNC. TigerVNC supports RandR and Xinerama extensions. xrandr is a command line interface to RandR.

Comment: Does TigerVNC support creating of virtual X server? What I want is: start a new x session in different TTY than the default and then start VNC server to use that session, but I want it to be independent from other x sessions on other TTYs.

Comment: @Jezor As I understand, Xvfb renders entirely in memory without dependence on a  physical output device. So it has nothing to do with TTYs. TigerVNC supplies a X server (Xvnc) that operates similar to Xvfb (no physical display device is needed) , except it supports more extensions and the rendered output is available to VNC clients. It works best with the TigerVNC client. You can start as many independent Xvnc sessions as you want.

Answer (score 2):

By specifying [`−fbdir` parameter](https://www.x.org/archive/X11R7.6/doc/man/man1/Xvfb.1.xhtml), it's creating *the memory mapped files containing the framebuffer memory*, not a frame buffer device.

According to [`fbset` manual](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/man1/fbset.1.html), the `-fb` accepts only frame buffer device node, not a memory mapped file. So I believe the proper syntax would be:

```
fbset -fb /dev/fb0 500x500
```

where `/dev/fb0` is your frame buffer device (e.g. `/dev/fb/0` or `/dev/fb0`).

To make frame buffer device known to X, define `FRAMEBUFFER` variable, e.g.

```
export FRAMEBUFFER=/dev/fb0
```

<sup>See also [`man fbdev`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/man4/fbdev.4.html) for more details.</sup>

To read `/tmp/Xvfb_screen0`, you should use `xwud` command instead, e.g.

```
xwud -in /var/tmp/Xvfb_screen0
```

which will displays screen 0 of the server.

---

Most likely it's not possible to change the resolution on the existing X server, so probably you need to re-run Xvfb server, or invoke another screen with different resolution.